# C# code to create graph in excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I m developing application in ASP.NET that will generate excel file and export data from Database to that excel file. I did it but I stuck on developing graphs in that excel file without storing data into excel sheet. For graph data comes from SQL server directly, I don't want to show and store data into excel sheet.
Please help.

Comment: I think it'll be a good idea if you paste the relevant code for us to have a look at and see where the problem is

Comment: I have not coded for the graph. But I got code which stores data into excel sheet first and then code the graph using excel range. But I don't want to do that, The Showing of graph data in range is not my client requirement. I want to show only graph not whole datatable

Comment: Which language are you writing in? C# or VB or both?

Comment: Instead of giving the chart a data range you could just put the values in there directly like `x values ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` but use the values from your database...